# Where to connect the eject cable

Tags: motherboard, dvd, eject

Hello I have bought the chasis of an [HP Slim Line S5747C](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=5051504) with the factory [motherboard](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01237548) and no DVD Rom. I added my own DVD Rom, but as you can see from the picture there is a separate eject button, which has a disconnected cable. Where should I connect that cable to? The motherboard or the DVD Rom? If it's the motherboard, which connector?

[image: Front plate]
[image: Back of the plate]
[image: Disconnected cable]

Comment: "*as you can see from the picture*" Actually, I can't. I have a hard time imagining the cable situation.

Comment: The eject button in the picture is a separate button from the eject button of the DVD Rom. That eject button has a cable that is disconnected. I imagine that cable was originally connected to something that would trigger the DVD Rom to eject. The problem is I don't know what that something is

Comment: More pictures coming soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further research, it appears that HP replaced the standard lever with a push-button to eject on this model. The connector is proprietary, to the left of the SATA connector on the HP optical drive shipped with the unit.

I've left the previous information here, in case it might aid a pre-5700 model owner.

---

The eject button on HP Slimline PCs is a mechanical lever that presses the physical eject button on the optical drive.

If there's a cable there, it isn't for the eject button.

The cable, if it leads to that area, is most likely the power/reset/HDD light front-panel harness, but I hesitate to state that without seeing the inside of that specific model.

[These end-of-life disassembly instructions](http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/globalcitizenship/environment/productdata/Countries/_MultiCountry/disassembly_deskto_2009625182814.pdf) may help you identify the cable.

Comment: "The eject button on HP Slimline PCs is a mechanical lever that presses the physical eject button on the optical drive." That is not the case on this model. I will post pictures later and edit the post

Comment: @jstawski Answer modified. It was probably silly of me to think HP wouldn't randomly add a useless proprietary connector to those at some point.

Comment: The end-of life document posted in the answer shows picture of a similar cable in questioned connected to the drive. Thus it seems like the cable should connect to the drive, but the drive i have doesn't have a pin for it. I guess I need to exchange it for another drive with the connector.

Answer (score 0):

If  a wire is coming out of the inside of the dvd eject button then it goes into optical dvd drive. The inside of the front appears to have a legacy manual eject but not applicable here. Connector goes in white port to left of sata power connector on dvd drive.

Answer (score 0):

Am now working on a slimline that has this type of DVD writer. It does indeed have a 2 pin connector on the back of the drive. I actually need to replace the drive as it is getting flakey. If you want to eject the drive using that button you will need to find the correct replacement drive though you can (1) find the drive in "My Computer, right click and select "eject or (2) use something like fingernails to open the door and push the normal eject button

Comment: This is essentially the same answer that has already been given and accepted. Please refrain from posting unless you actually have something new and valuable to add to the solution.